# Suggest new tag for one-sided (or one-tailed) P value

Tags: support

If you search for "one tail" or "one sided", there are tons of hits. Glancing quickly, most of them really are about interpreting or choosing one-sided (one-tailed) tests. I think a tag would be helpful.

What about "Two sided" and "two tails". Another tag? Or make the tag more general: "One vs. two sided tests"??

I'm not sure if this is the right way to propose a new tag, but others have done so in meta, and I can't see an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have 300 reputation, you can create tags; so you're free to do so.  You simply edit an appropriate question and type the name you want for your new tag in the **tags** field (supposing there aren't 5 tags already--that's the limit).  If the tag doesn't end up on at least one more question within six months, it will be automatically deleted.  For more information, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Regarding the merits of this proposal, I personally don't have strong opinions.  You've done the research, if there are recurring on-topic questions about this issue, then we should have a tag for them.  Here are a couple of suggestions I have about tag creation:

- I think it would be better to have one tag than two.
- You can't have spaces between words, you have to put a dash "-".
- My guess is that 'tailed' is more common terminology than 'sided'.
- It's best for tags to have names that are as short as possible.
- If there are several names that might work almost as well, you could preempt them by asking the moderators to create them and make them synonyms of your new tag.

So a possible name might be: `[1-vs-2-tailed]`, but I'm sure someone else might be able to come up with a better name.